# Issue with Sum on a colum in Rdlc Report

Tags: asp.net, expression, rdlc

I have a rdlc report.

Supposing there are two columns

```
   Trval      Status
   10000        YES
   20000        YES
   30000        NO

Total= 30000
```

Currently i am using this expression to get the above:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Lead_Status.Value = "YES", Fields!TrValRange.Value, 0))
```

Assuming it will add the  TrValRange to the result each time its a YES. But in case where
there are no Status=YES it says 0. However when there are rows with `Status=YES` it gives `ERROR` .

Also TrValRange is a string field do we need some sort of conversion here to Sum? Any suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i thought needed to convert the string value to int so it can be summed changed the expression to :

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Lead_Status.Value = "Satisfactory",CInt(Fields!TrValRange.Value), 0))
```

And it works perfectly.